# Get full link JS (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I using JS to generate link to controller

Like this

```
<script>
    $("#mybutton").click(function () {
        $("#link").val('@Url.Action("Welcome","Interwier")');
    });
</script>
```

But I need to get full link like `http://*****.***/Interwier/Welcome`

How I can do this?

Comment: why you need full url ?

Comment: maybe because I need to paste those url to users?@Shyju

Comment: what about `$("#link").val(document.location.origin + '@Url.Action("Welcome","Interwier")');`

Comment: Yes. It works. But you forgot `.` after `document`@MahediSabuj

Comment: Thank's dude so much @MahediSabuj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get full link of current page through

```
location.href
```

and to get link of current controller

```
location.href.substring(0,location.href.lastIndexOf('/'));
```